# Icons in Files are huge now and I can't figure out how to make them default size again

Tags: icons, files

I'm not sure what I did, but all of the icons in Files are huge now and I can't find a solution on how to make them back to default size. Apologies for the likely stupid question, but I can't find anything online about it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:
Hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and using your mouse wheel.